# Difference between "I'm only telling you just what I heard from him" and "I'm just telling you only what I heard from him"

Tags: adverbs

> I'm **only** telling you **just** what I heard from him.

I'm wondering if it is possible to switch the places of "just" and "only".

> I'm **just** telling you **only** what I heard from him.

Do they have different meanings?

Comment: It would be helpful if you consider what the adverb (only) modifies (in context) to understand its effect. The first is *only "telling you". The second is *only* "what I heard from him". However, in the second example *only* could also be read as "you" *only*, in which the meaning would be the same as the first example.

Answer (score 1):

The "objective" meaning is the same (although the first contains ambiguity which could be read the way Sotondolphin mentions). The difference is in emphasis on *why* the extra information is not being told.

Oh, and the "just" in the first adds immediacy. Let's drop it from the explanation for clarity.

> I'm only telling you what I heard from him.

I'm not adding any extra information, anything I might know on the subject from other sources - I'm **withholding extra information.** I'm not giving you any extra clues or my opinions. You are meant to draw your own conclusions, solve it all by yourself etc - the extra information might be valuable, but for some specific reason I believe you shouldn't obtain it from me.

> I'm just telling you what I heard from him.

I'm reporting his message faithfully, without alterations. If I added or changed anything, it would falsify the message. I **don't alter the message**, because it's more valuable in its pure form than if I augmented or changed it in any way.

The extra *just* in the first sentence only marks the information as recent: it's been minutes, or at most hours since I heard what I'm telling you (and possibly I'm withholding whatever he had said earlier).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm only telling you what I just heard from him.

Which means you won't tell anybody else what you heard from him.

> I'm just telling you what I heard from him.

This means that you may hear something from many other people, but you only tell the one you heard from "HIM"

Comment: You left *only* out of the second example.